# Interface in a WCF DTO

Tags: c#, wcf

I try to transmit a DTO (WCF client to WCF server) which contains a suboject with an interface.

My code:

WCF Service Method:

```
[OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true)]
public void SendTest(MyTestDto testDto)
{
  ...
}
```

MyTestDto class:

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract(Name = "MyTestDto")]
public class MyTestDto : ITestDto
{
   [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Order = 1, Name = "MyTestDto")]
   [DataMemberValidation(IsRequired = true)]
   public ITest Test { get; set; }

}
```

ITest interface:

```
public interface ITest
{
    int Field1 {get;set;}
    int Field2 {get;set,}
}
```

The problem is, that I get always an `FaultException` if I will transmit the MyTestDto from Server to Client. I've analysed the WSDL File and the Test Field had the Type: `AnyType`. I think, this is the problem. I've replaced the `ITest` with an abstract class and so the communication works (of course I have to set the `ServiceKnownType` attribute with the abstract class).

Can you help me? Why does it work with the abstract class and not with the interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF works with concrete types, interfaces can not be serialized over WCF.

Making the interface an abstract class works only if you marked the service with `ServiceKnownType` or the data contract with `KnownType` attributes. Below is an example;

```
public abstract Test
{
    public int Field1 {get;set;}
    public int Field2 {get;set,}
}

public class SomeTest : Test
{ 
    ...
}

[ServiceKnownType(typeof(SomeTest))]
public class SomeService : ISomeService
{
     public void SendTest(Test test)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know this, but I can set the concrete type of the interface e.g. with the KnownType or ServiceKnownType Attribute?!

Comment: not possible to send an interface over wire; you need to declare an abstract class as a base instead of an interface.